# python if-condition based on int intput

Tags: python

I want to print out a message if user input is != 0 or 1.

```
entering = int(input('enter 0 or 1: '))
```

I can get it to work for either 0 or 1, but when I try to combine both in one if-condition, it doesn't work. Following 2 options I tried:

```
if entering != 0 or entering != 1:
    print('invalid input')

if entering != 0 or 1:
    print('invalid input')
```

If I then enter 0 or 1, it still prints 'invalid input'. What am I missing?

Comment: just curious, why do people sometimes downgrade normal questions? did I do anything wrong in the way I asked this question?

Comment: It's called a "downvote" and you got some because this question is exceedingly basic, and could have been answered by simply reading your textbook. It is not clear that you performed any research before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to exclude values of 0 *and* 1, so the condition must be an *and* expression, not an *or* expression.

```
if entering != 0 and entering != 1:
    print('invalid input')
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, one of the conditions is guaranteed to be true: if `entering ==0`, then `entering != 1` and vice versa. In the second case, it is evaluated as `(entering != 0) or 1`, and `1` is always true.

You want `and`:

```
if entering != 0 and entering != 1:
```

or the `not in` operator:

```
if entering not in [0,1]:
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite as:

```
while True:
    entry=input('enter 0 or 1: ') #raw_input if Python 2
    if entry in ('0','1'):
        user_input=int(entry)
        break
    else:
        print 'Invalid Entry'
```